# Clearing memory after generating and saving matplotlib figures in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib, memory-management

I have some simulation data that I want to use to generate a movie. The simulation has 8000 individual time steps that are saved in an hdf5 format which I load and store in a variable as a "history" class. This history class allows me to iterate through the history object and do some analysis and generate a figure based on that. I do this with a for loop and generate a figure using matplotlib, and save it to disk with every loop iteration. After about 100 loops the code crashes with a memory error. The code is shown below, with certain details removed for conciseness. How can I make it so that the memory and figures is cleared after each loop? I've tried a few of the solutions for similar issues on other threads but none of them seem to be directly applicable - apologies if I missed anything. Thanks!

Here is my code, I've included all the details but some of the code might not make sense since it uses a lot of custom code and a specific library.

`#load hdf5 file
history = HistoryHdf5.from_archive("CW_0.5_1.hf5")

#iterate over all time steps
for times in np.arange(0, 800, 0.1):

```
sheet = all_quartet_composition_edge(history, times)

identify_rosettes(sheet)

draw_specs = tyssue.config.draw.sheet_spec()

color = sheet.edge_df["composition"]
sheet.face_df["color"] = 0
sheet.face_df["chirality"] = "CW"
sheet.face_df.loc[sheet.face_df["torque_coef"] == 0.2, "color"] = 1
sheet.face_df.loc[sheet.face_df["torque_coef"] == 0.2, "chirality"] = "CCW"
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(["black", 'red', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange', 'yellow'])
cmap2 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(["white", "black"])
color_map = cmap(color)
color_map2 = cmap2(sheet.face_df["color"])
color_map3 = cmap2(sheet.vert_df["rosette"])
draw_specs['face']['color'] = "white"
draw_specs['face']['visible'] = True
draw_specs['face']['alpha'] = 0.2
draw_specs['vert']['visible'] = True
draw_specs['vert']['color'] = color_map3
draw_specs['vert']['alpha'] = sheet.vert_df["rosette"]
draw_specs['edge']['color'] = color_map
draw_specs['edge']['head_width'] = 0.01
draw_specs['edge']['width'] = 2
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (12, 12), dpi = 300)
fig, ax = sheet_view(sheet, ["x", "y"], ax, **draw_specs)

black_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='black', label='Boundary/Rosette')
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Homogenous')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='3:1 Heterogenous')
purple_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='purple', label='3:1 Homogenous')
orange_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', label='2:2 Heteroogenous')
yellow_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='yellow', label='2:2 Homogenous')

plt.legend(handles=[black_patch, red_patch, blue_patch, purple_patch, orange_patch,   yellow_patch])

for face, data in sheet.face_df.iterrows():
    ax.text(data.x-0.3, data.y, sheet.face_df["chirality"][face], fontsize=4, color="b")
    
fig.savefig(f"test_{times}.png")

plt.cla()
plt.clf()
plt.close(fig)`
```